# Check if <p> is first child

Tags: javascript, jquery

This the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KGDyR/

I need to add class on (each) p inside (each) div

If the p is the first child of div tag, add class .first

If not add .notfirst

So the output will be like this

```
<div>
    <p class="first">p is first</p>
    <img src="http://projectfoo.com/images/foo_logo.gif" />
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://projectfoo.com/images/foo_logo.gif" />
    <p class="notfirst">p is not first</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest, for simplicity:

```
$('p').addClass(function(){
    return this.previousElementSibling === null ? 'first' : 'notfirst';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGDyR/).

Or, to work in those browsers that don't support `previousElementSibling`:

```
$('p').addClass(function(){
    return !$(this).prev().length ? 'first' : 'notfirst';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGDyR/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`Element.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.previousElementSibling).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Answer (score 5):

Use [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$("div p:first-child").addClass('first')
```

then [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("div p:not(:first-child)").addClass('notfirst')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQQqU/)

Comment: While I don't see the point of using two separate selectors for this, why use `:not()`, when you could use the simpler: `$('div * + p')`? Incidentally, while your [approach of two separate collections is faster](http://jsperf.com/testing-alternate-selectors), my amendment improves it *slightly* (very, *very*, ***very*** slightly...) :)

Answer (score 0):

The other way.

```
$('div').each(function(index, obj) {
    var c = $(this).is(':first-child') ? 'first' : 'notfirst';
    $(this).find('p').addClass(c);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the `first` and `notfirst` classes for styling, you can target these elements purely with CSS, via `p:first-child` and `* + p` (ie. a `p` element that has a previous sibling and is therefore not a first child).

If you're adding the classes for other reasons (another script?) then you will need Javascript (as per [Davis Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196651/180500), say). However, at the point where you add the classes, you've already had to grab those elements with Javascript, so why not do whatever you want to do at that point? In most (possibly not absolutely all, but most) cases it would be unnecessary to use Javascript to add classes that act as Javascript hooks, since you've already had to get the elements in question.

In other words, if you're using the classes for styling, you don't need Javascript; if you're using them as Javascript hooks, you probably don't need those classes.